# Pandas: Create column of copy value to cells bellow it based on IF condition

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have this following dataset:

Current:

```
Date        User  Action    Location  Reason 
2008-05-23  A     password  NaN       Provided
2008-05-27  A     connect   Paris     NaN
2008-05-28  B     password  NaN       Provided
2008-05-29  B     connect   London    NaN
2008-05-30  c     password  NaN       Note Provided
2008-05-30  c     connect   NY        NaN
2008-05-28  d     password  NaN       Provided
2008-05-29  e     password  NaN       Note Provided
2008-05-30  e     connect   Paris     NaN
```

With excel I can use this  formula:`=IF(AND(Table1[@Reason]='',Table1[@Action]='Password'),IF(ISBLANK(D3),D4,D3),)` to create a new column in order to have all the information at the same row,see as bellow:

Desired:

```
Date        User  Action    Location  Reason         NEW_COLUMN
2008-05-23  A     password  NaN       Provided       Paris
2008-05-27  A     connect   Paris     NaN            0
2008-05-28  B     password  NaN       Provided       London
2008-05-29  B     connect   London    NaN            0
2008-05-30  c     password  NaN       Note Provided  NY
2008-05-30  c     connect   NY        NaN            0
2008-05-28  d     password  NaN       Provided       NaN    
2008-05-29  e     password  NaN       Note Provided  Paris
2008-05-30  e     connect   Paris     NaN            0
```

I want to apply the same logic with Pandas but I'm having a hard time to tackle this problem especially on the second part of my formula. So far I've tried to apply this [`code`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352669/dataframe-if-value-in-a-cell-copy-value-to-cells-below-it) but with no success

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If there is always order `password` and `connect` in column `Action` is possible use [`GroupBy.bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.bfill.html) for back filling missing value and then set new column in [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for test masks for misisng values (if one row group) with compare `Action` by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==`:

```
new = df.groupby('User')['Location'].bfill()
mask1 = new.notna()
mask2 = df['Action'].eq('password')

df['NEW_COLUMN'] = np.select([mask1 & mask2, mask1 & ~mask2], [new, 0], None)
print (df)
         Date User    Action Location         Reason NEW_COLUMN
0  2008-05-23    A  password      NaN       Provided      Paris
1  2008-05-27    A   connect    Paris            NaN          0
2  2008-05-28    B  password      NaN       Provided     London
3  2008-05-29    B   connect   London            NaN          0
4  2008-05-30    c  password      NaN  Note Provided         NY
5  2008-05-30    c   connect       NY            NaN          0
6  2008-05-28    d  password      NaN       Provided       None
7  2008-05-29    e  password      NaN  Note Provided      Paris
8  2008-05-30    e   connect    Paris            NaN          0
```